# после чтения CSV при помощи pd.read_csv() последний столбец содержит только NaN

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

При запуске кода возникает ошибка:'ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'h''
В датасете f и h это метки с названиями классов объектов.(Фрагмент датасета и код прилагаю) 
Изначально классификатор обучался на базе данных с ирисами Фишера и с ними всё работало нормально, хотя в колонке с классами там тоже находятся строки.
Подскажите как исправить, буду благодарен

```
import sklearn
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
import time
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier

df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Ilyas\\Documents\\StrngStuff\\dft.csv', index_col = 0)
X = df.loc[:, '1f':'2f'] #Характеристики
y = df.loc[:, 'Pr'] #Метки
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size= .5)
def print_accuracy(f):
    print("Accuracy = {0}%".format(100*np.sum(f(X_test) == y_test)/len(y_test)))
    time.sleep(0.5)
nn1 = MLPClassifier(activation='relu', solver='lbfgs', alpha=1e-1, hidden_layer_sizes=(5, 2), random_state=0)
nn1.fit(X_train, y_train)
print_accuracy(nn1.predict)
```

Фрагмент датасета, в других частях f заменено на h

```
,1f,2f,Pr
6.78E-09,0.000000029,"f"
1.71885E-07,7.36621E-07,"f"
1.1053E-06,4.74247E-06,"f"
1.09928E-05,0.000047261,"f"
2.45313E-05,0.000105561,"f"
4.79299E-05,0.000206426,"f"
0.000139912,0.000603569,"f"
0.000217298,0.000938154,"f"
0.000321944,0.001391043,"f"
0.00045879,0.001983876,"f"
0.000848963,0.003676757,"f"
0.001112029,0.004819806,"f"
0.001426622,0.006188141,"f"
0.002227449,0.009676944,"f"
```

[image: Сам датасет]

[image: X_train]

[image: y_train]

[image: Изначальный датасет]

Comment: Вы можете воспроизвести ошибку на датасете из вопроса? У меня все работает... Похоже в реальной программе у вас `label` (target) попадает в `X_train`...

Comment: А каким образом это может произойти? Код точно такой же, ничего не пропущено. Датасет, вроде как тоже, но на 200 значений, 100 на f и 100 на h

Comment: @MaxU, я приложу к самому вопросу то, как распологаются данные после разделения. Я не могу понять, почему всё происходит именно так, но вы правы и X_train по какой то причине содержит метки, но я не могу понять, как они туда попадают, ибо y_train их в свою очередь не содержит(в нем дублируется первый столбец). Насколько я понял, проблема в датасете, ибо в нем, по какой то причине смещены наименования столбцов.

Comment: ну например в вашем датасете из вопроса - столбец с индексами отсутствует и в заголовке первая запятая - лишняя... Покажите несколько строк вашего реального датасета - скорее всего там похожая проблема

Comment: @MaxU, если я правильно понял, запятая в начале является лишней?

Comment: да, я дал пояснения в ответе...

Comment: @MaxU, благодарю, проблема решена. При создании датасета по подобию тому, на котором изначально тестировалась, не была учтена индексация.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Похоже у вас некорректный заголовок CSV файла - если заголовок CSV файл начинается с запятой и вы используете `df = pd.read_csv(fname, index_col=0)`, то значения из первого столбца будут восприниматься как значения индекса, хотя, судя по данным, значения индекса в CSV файле отсутствуют.

Попробуйте убрать первую запятую в строке заголовке (первая строка) в CSV вручную и **не** используйте параметр `index_col=0`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Ilyas\\Documents\\StrngStuff\\dft.csv')
```